# Why does Vim respect my vimrc on new files but not on old files?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc file I have the options `set wrap` and `set lbr` which are telling Vim to wrap lines and to do so at whitespace / certain punctuation marks. Functionally this works fine on new files. Writing my name over and over wraps the text between names without inserting a newline.

If I open an older file from when I had some different settings (which I don't remember) Vim inserts newlines whenever it wraps. Old wrapped text remains, wrapping correctly but remaining on its own line 'number'. I can `set lbr` and Vim correctly wraps all the old lines at the end of the line rather than whitespace as expected, `set nowrap` will remove all my wraps, putting each line on a new 'numbered' line. Setting these two commands back again puts the file back how it was. For some reason any new wrap in this file is just misbehaving.

Is there a logical reason for this seemingly random behaviour?

Comment: Old files doing one thing and new files doing another is, in _no_ sense, random. Even seemingly so :-)

Comment: Well aware that nothing in computing is random, especially rand(). Nonsensical?

Comment: there might be some plugin/autocmd changing your settings, use `verbose set wrap/lbr` to check

Comment: Do your old files have modelines and new ones not, or vice versa? Are both old ones and new ones of the same type?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use *sessions* or *views*, or related plugins? With the default option values, the `'wrap'` and `'lbr'` settings may have been persisted and recalled. In general, you can find out where the option got set via

```
:verbose setlocal wrap? lbr?
```

Comment: `wrap` and `lbr` were both being set by ~/_vimrc, no sessions or views on an otherwise vanilla install.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the behaviour on a number of files, the behaviour is caused by the ".txt" file extension.
Creating a new file in Vim with no extension behaves correctly. When the file is saved with ".txt" on the end and re-opened, it misbehaves, removing ".txt" corrects the behaviour

The problem is being caused by Vim's filetype detection and its preference to wrap text in an 'intelligent' method that I imagine preserves the wrapping when the file is opened in another text editor which doesn't support wrapping.

Comment: `.txt` files have the `text` filetype and as far as I can tell there are local setting for this filetype for vanilla vim. So it is more than likely you have some setting and/or plugins affecting your text files. It should be noted that both `'wrap'` and `'lbr'` are setting local to a window not a buffer so they may be left over from a different buffer.

Comment: I mistyped. There are *no* local settings for the filetype `text` for vanilla vim.